# Laravel 9 Delete Confirmation with SweetAlert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

I am trying to delete data from resource controller with sweetalert in laravel 9. However, it is not working.

**blade.php**

```
 <a href="{{ route('employee.destroy', $item->id) }}" onclick="confirmation(event)">Delete</a>
```

**controller**

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        Employee::findorFail($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('employee.index');
        Alert::toast('Employee Deleted', 'Employee has been deleted successfully');
    }
```

**script**

```
  <script>
        function confirmation(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var urlToRedirect = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
            console.log(urlToRedirect);
            new swal({
                    title: "Are you sure to delete this business?",
                    text: "You will not be able to revert this!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,
                    dangerMode: true,
                })
                .then((willCancel) => {
                    if (willCancel) {
                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
                            },
                        });
                        $.ajax({
                            Method: "DELETE",
                            url: urlToRedirect,
                            data: {
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                location.href = location.href;
                            },
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
```

I could not figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Does the sweetalert fires?

Comment: yes it does. but when I click on ok. it reloads but doesn't delete the data.

Comment: Try debugging with `dd($id);` inside the `destroy` method to see if you are getting the correct `$id`

Comment: the data is getting deleted without sweet alert confirmation. However, it is not getting deleted when using sweet alert confirmation box.

Comment: Hi, you are not passing `id` in ajax call . Not seeing any parameter in `data..{`

Comment: @Swati how do I pass it? Could you please go through  my code? I had tried it but got an error

Comment: This might be because the response from the server is not being returned as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, I had forgotten to return in JSON in the controller. Also, I had added sweetalert twice. That was the issue.

```js
function confirmation(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var urlToRedirect = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
  console.log(urlToRedirect);
  new swal({
    title: "Are you sure to delete this business?",
    text: "You will not be able to revert this!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  })
    .then((willCancel) => {
      if (willCancel) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
          },
        });
        $.ajax({
          type: "DELETE",
          url: urlToRedirect,
          data: {
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
          },
          success: function(data) {
            location.href = location.href;
          },
        });
      }
    });
}
```

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  Employee::findorFail($id)->delete();
  return response()->json(['status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Employee deleted successfully.'], 200);
}
```